# django modelform exclude field still shown

Tags: django

django 1.3:

I have an excluded field in my ModelForm and it still shows up when building the form with .as_table(), as_p() methods, etc

I have tried in both in a template file and in the shell, the exclude field shows up in the exclude variable, but it doesn't seem to impact.

Model:

```
class UserTrans(models.Model):
    usertransid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='userid')
    transdate = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date")
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'usertrans'


class TransForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=UserTrans
        exclude = ('userid',)
```

When I open the shell and try:

```
x=TransForm()
x.as_table()
```

or in a template

```
{{ form.as_table }} or 
{{ form.as_p }}
```

It shows the userid field along with the rest of the fields.
If I try `x.exclude` it shows me `('userid',)` so I know the syntax is correct.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to exclude another field, like data? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure there is something else going on that is not shown in your code. However, there is a hack for this. Give your modelform an `__init__` in which you delete 'userid' from the form's `fields` property (which is a dict).

Comment: I haven't figured it out, but when I ran each piece seperately in the shell it does work. But when run all together it doesn't. So it must be something in my code.

Comment: @user1201972: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: No. I am learning django now and don't want to use a workaround for something that is described in the docs as should be working. At this point I prefer to figure out where the bug in my code is.

Comment: @user1201972: Good luck with that. Django's modelforms sometimes throw up strange behaviour, and you have to just work around it.